# Can you pass an array thru props in Svelte?

Tags: svelte

Can you pass an array through props in Svelte?

```
<script>
    import List
    let array = [];
    console.log(array);
</script>

<List list=array/>
```

```
<script>
    export let array;
    console.log(array);
</script>
```

This will produce: 
(1st log) []
(2nd log) array

But I thought it would produce
(1st log) []
(2nd log) []

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can pass any value as a prop.

The problem here is that you're doing `list=array`, which is just passing the string `"array"`, rather than `list={array}`. [See the tutorial to learn the syntax](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/dynamic-attributes).